# Dynamically created links are not showing in search results

Tags: search, seo, web-crawler, google-search

I have pages on my website such as:

```
/sign-in
/about
/user/1203
/1203/post/19298
```

The sign in and about page are indexed with Google and show up however the last 2 pages do not. The user and post pages are dynamically created, so depending on the number entered, different users/posts show. Would this make a difference when a search engine crawls a page?

My robots.txt allows these URLs to be indexed but my sitemap.xml cannot contain the user and post pages as the values in the url are not constant e.g. a user page url could be `/user/324` or `/user/948`.

Are there any reasons why these pages are not being indexed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They will get indexed eventually, to make sure that happens faster, if possible to name your posts by name such as example.com/post/what-wonderful-day instead of example.com/posts/123 also go to google webmaster tools and use fetch as google spider then submit your post or user URL, it will get indexed fast. Note: you are allowed 500 submissions per month, other wise you just have to wait.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some posts have been up for a couple months and still don't appear when specifically search for my website.

Comment: Could you provide me your website URL to check it, i do know some pages do not show indexed for few reasons which are not technical but due to content or rank blockage.